# What is the term for "the act of cutting a word in the middle, add a hyphen, and put the rest in the next line because it's too long"?

Tags: word-request

So it's some-

thing like this.

This probably something trivia, but I don't know the keyword to search for the term in english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually just called **hyphenation**, although sometimes it's referred to broadly as *paragraph hyphenation*.

From [Mellel](https://www.mellel.com/mellel-flare/Content/Topics/Styling%20your%20Document/Paragraph%20Formatting/Managing%20Paragraph%20Hyphenation.htm):

> **Managing Paragraph Hyphenation**
>
> Hyphenation is splitting a word in two at the end of a line. A hyphen (-) is inserted in the middle of the word at the end of the line, and the rest of the word is moved to the next line. Hyphenation is often used with text in columns and when the text is fully justified, to allow dividing the text into lines of approximately even length. Hyphenation does not change the actual text, just its rendering across different lines. . . .
>
> Hyphenation is not applied blindly whenever a word is too long to fit in a certain line. The decision whether or not to hyphenate follows a certain logic. This logic is partly configured by the user and partly based on an hyphenation dictionary which details what words can be split and how.

There's a question at [English Language & Users](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line) that talks about the particular rules around it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know that I'm so close to the answer but didn't realize it. I'm searching for a plugin that can make text in application automatically hyphenate, but I can't find it just by using the word "hyphen". Now I can find a bunch of them. Thanks!